# c++ pack / unpack

Tags: php, c++, pack, unpack

I am trying to understand how pack/unpack from PHP works.

as I see from [php.net/pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

```
n     unsigned short (always 16 bit, big endian byte order)
```

i have in php

```
$binarydata = unpack('n', 12);
print_r($binarydata);
```

Output:

```
Array (
     [1] => 12594
)
```

in C++ I have

```
uint16_t swap_uint16( uint16_t val ) {
  return (val << 8) | (val >> 8 );
}
cout << swap_uint16(12);
```

> Output: 3072

Comment: Your PHP code makes no sense. Your C++ code makes sense but I don't see what it has to do with either your PHP code or the `pack` documentation you quoted. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP's `unpack` **converts** 12 into string "12". In bytes representation it is: `0x31 0x32`. Now convert PHP's output (12594) into hex number ))

Comment: heh, just beat me to it.  :)

Comment: everything is very clear now! thank you xD !